Is it possible to send Jito Bundles without using their API?
Currently I am using their API to send my bundles to the validator. Is it possible to somehow directly send it, in order to improve speed?

What do you mean by "directly send it"? Bundles can only be processed by Jito block engines, so there's nothing faster than sending it to their block engine
